# WPF ItemControl Virtualisation

Tags: wpf, virtualization, itemscontrol

I need to bind some data to Items control which I get from solr. Solr gives fast results, but I feel that binding takes long time. so, is there anyway I could improve the performance by implementing virtualization ? If so,please give me some suggestions from where I could start to.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of virtualization:

Data virtualization
UI Virtualization

Data virtualization is not implemented by WPF controls. It consists of loading data from a source as required, some kind of batch.

UI Virtualization is implemented by default in WPF controls. It consists of loading to memory only what is shown. But in databinding scenarios all data structure is loaded.

Alternatives?

1) If you are using MVVM pattern, you could have a collection in you ViewModel which would contain partial data from your Solr query, for example the 20 first results, like a pagination.

2) If you are exposing your data in a DataGrid, I would suggest you the [Infragistics DataGrid for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/sfdatagrid), it is built in with Data virtualization feature, and has a community license

I hope I could helped you :)

Comment: Thanks ! I'll get back to you if in case i have any questions

Comment: What i have previously tried is, using a virtualising stack panel inside my data template. But , my application gets crashed !

Comment: Please,  if my answer helped you,  check it as answered or give a +1